# Country/currency in google merchant feed?

Tags: google-merchant-center

I have a Google Merchant feed for India, which uses the Indian rupee as its currency. Now, my client wants to launch a campaign in the USA for the same products, but with US dollars as the currency. The question is whether I should create a new merchant feed specifically for the USA with dollars, or if I can use the existing rupee-based feed for the US market as well. Interestingly, a Google representative informed my client that the rupee-based feed could also be used for the USA market. Should I inform the client that he would indeed need a separate feed for each country?

i tried the same feed, but it didn't work out